# Unable to call com registered dll function in php

Tags: c#, php, .net, com, dcom

I have completed the com registration of a dll file and it is showing in the registry(which I got after entering `regedit` in command prompt)
If I use `$obj1 = new COM("Encryptiondll.ClsEncryption");` I am getting no error
But when I am trying to access a method(which is declared as public string in .net) I am getting the following error from my php code
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method com::Encrypt12() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\index.php on line 12`
Please help
Below is the c# code I used to constract the dll:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Encryptiondll
{
    public class ClsEncryption
    {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
       public static string Encrypt12(string plaintext)
        {

            ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] key = textConverter.GetBytes("2a1c907916add59edffb3a4b");
            byte[] IV = textConverter.GetBytes("00000000");
            byte[] clearData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext);
            byte[] cipherData = Encrypt1(clearData, key, IV);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherData);
        }
        public static byte[] Encrypt1(byte[] clearData, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ICryptoTransform alg = tdes.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            cs.Close();
            byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
            return encryptedData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some code?  No one is about to guess what your C# code looks like.

Comment: I have added the code I am using to generate the dll

Comment: Ok, you have static methods, COM doesn't know anything about them because .NET won't tell anything about them.  For that, they must be instance methods.  Also, your class must be COM-visible, but from the description you gave early in the question, I guess it already is.